# Bits and Files in Python

Tags: python

Suppose that I have a file as input that is 4 Bytes, and I would like to output:

```
bit + first two bytes + bit + last two bytes
```

Where the added bits are just flags. How can I do this in python (using only built-in functions) such that the new file is only 5 bytes (2 bits + 4bytes ~= 5 bytes).

I am familiar with the `file.read(x)` and other I/O operations, but the part that I am unsure about is how to add the bits.

**Edit**: I was able to solve this problem using the [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) python library. This module has the support to do all what I wanted:

- Read bytes from a file into a bit array using `fromfile()`
- append bits using `append(True/False)`
- appending a variable with
  specific size using `frombytes()` and the python standard [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)
  module.
- Writing the bit array to a file (with padding if needed) using `tofile()`

You can also use the [`python-bitstring`](https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) module to get similar results.

Comment: Is the output format already predefined(project requirement) to be exactly like that? If it is not I would write the bits(flags) completely separately from the data part.

Comment: Yes, I am required to have the flags precede the data.

Comment: I have added my solution in an edit. please vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [bit wise](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) operators

```
flag1 = 1
flag2 = 1
flag1 = flag1
flag2 = flag2 << 17 # (2 bytes + 1 bit under it)  
byte1 = byte1 << 1  # (1 bit )
byte2 = byte2 << 18 # (2 bytes + 2 bits underit)

out = flag1 & flag2 & byte1 & byte2 # stack them up
```

Comment: I will need to do this for a whole file and add bits at arbitrary locations. How would this scale?

Comment: Carefully.  In conjunction with `struct` for getting bytes in and out of files.  It isn't too hard to generalize this code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `struct` module to pack the bits and bytes into a string, then write it to a file.

Comment: struct might work except that all basic types are still in 1 byte increments, so the resulting output will be 6 bytes which is not what I want. Look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters